# Popular inputs de acordo com o valor do option selecionado

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho 3 arrays, cidades, capitais e população. Como posso fazer ao clicar em um determinado estado aparecer nos inputs os respectivos valores, ou seja, capital e população do estado selecionado.

```js
var cidades = new Array("Acre", "Bahia", "Minas Gerais", "Pernambuco", "Rio de Janeiro", "São Paulo") 
var capital = new Array("Rio Branco", "Salvador", "Belo Horizonte", "Recife", "Rio de Janeiro", "São Paulo") 
var populacao = new Array("829.619", "15.344.447", "21.119.536", "9.473.266", "16.718.956", "45.094.866" ) 

function getData() { 
   var estado = document.getElementById("estados");
   document.getElementById("capital").value = ?????
   document.getElementById("populacao").value = ????
} 

getData();
```

```html
Selecione o estado: 
<select id="estados" onChange="getData(this.form)"> 
   <option>Acre</option>
   <option>Bahia</option>
   <option>Minas Gerais</option>
   <option>Pernambuco</option>
   <option>Rio de Janeiro</option>
   <option>São Paulo</option>
</select> 
<br>
A capital é: 
<input type="text" id="capital" size=13> 
<br> 
A população é: 
<input type="text" id="populacao" size=6>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trata-se de arrays paralelos. Dizem-se paralelos se os seus elementos identificados pelo mesmo indice estão relacionados.

Como os valores de indice das opções dentro do elemento SELECT combinam com os dos valores de indice de array paralelo, a propriedade selectedindex do elemento SELECT cria um modo conveniente de se chegar diretamente aos dados correspondentes em outros arrays

Na função crie uma variavel index,

```
Var index = document.getElementById("estados").selectedindex
```

Utilize essa variavel 'index' para retornar os respectivos itens  dos outros arrays, substitua os pontos de interrogação  por capital[index] e populacao[index]

Answer (score 1):

Na função `getData()` é passado um parâmetro, o valor do índice de cada `<option>`, depois ele pega o parâmetro por **JS** e utiliza como índice do array:

```js
var cidades = new Array("Acre", "Bahia", "Minas Gerais", "Pernambuco", "Rio de Janeiro", "São Paulo");
var capital = new Array("Rio Branco", "Salvador", "Belo Horizonte", "Recife", "Rio de Janeiro", "São Paulo");
var populacao = new Array("829.619", "15.344.447", "21.119.536", "9.473.266", "16.718.956", "45.094.866" );
function getData(valor){
   document.getElementById("capital").value = capital[valor];
   document.getElementById("populacao").value = populacao[valor];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>teste</title>
</head>
<body>
   Selecione o estado:
   <select id="estados" onChange="getData(this.value)"> 
      <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Selecione o Estado</option>
      <option value="0">Acre</option>
      <option value="1">Bahia</option>
      <option value="2">Minas Gerais</option>
      <option value="3">Pernambuco</option>
      <option value="4">Rio de Janeiro</option>
      <option value="5">São Paulo</option>
   </select> 
   <br>
   A capital é: 
   <input type="text" id="capital" disabled="disabled" size=13> 
   <br> 
   A população é: 
   <input type="text" id="populacao" disabled="disabled" size=6>
</body>
</html>
```

Obs: Coloque mais uma opção no `<option>` para que o Acre pudesse ser selecionado também (como está `disabled` não passa valor).